# Ajax call not sending data via Post

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I am attempting to make an Ajax call from a modal dialog in my MVC app.  See Ajax code below.  When I click the button on my form, it successfully makes the ajax call, and hits a breakpoint on my controller (code below).  It pops up the success Alert as well.  It doesn't pass the email address to the function on my controller.  The value of email is null when it hits my breakpoint.  I read about it passing name/value pairs in query string but that is empty as well.  How can I pass the string value to my function?

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendAjaxRequest(element, urlToSend) {
        var  email = $("#NewEmail").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlToSend,
            data: "{email: " + email + "}",
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Send code to ' + email);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SendCodeButton").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();                                         // This prevents him from posting back on the form
            sendAjaxRequest($(this), '/Home/SendEmailVerification/');
        });
    });        
</script>
```

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SendEmailVerification(string email)
    {
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: Your attribute data is wrong, change `data: "{email: " + email + "}"` for `data: {email: email}`.

Comment: The comment by Benilson is the answer.